# iPhone 7 Plus - Both Cameras partially not working properly

Tags: iphone, photos, video, camera

We have an old iPhone 7 Plus, and it has been used by 2 of the members in my family, and now they have upgraded to 13's and 14's with this phone being mine.

Despite the fact that iOS 15.7 is the latest you can install, one should have no complaint with even this old iPhone. But the problem with mine is that, I don't know how or when, maybe it got dropped or something, and now it's cameras are having problems.

The rear facing camera shutters heavily, the picture shakes, and the camera produces audible rattling notices (I might link an photos/audio/video if required). <strike>The front camera is produces pictures pitch black, with only bright light sources (light bulbs) visible, rest dark.</strike> NOTE that even after this, the interesting thing is that the Phone has ***no*** problems in recording  slo-mo video from the rear camera (AFAIK slo-mo is in rear only), and it works perfectly.

If the cameras were really damaged, why would slo-mo work?

UPDATE:
The front camera was not damaged, though it was almost covered with a damaged screen protector/film. I removed it, and front camera picture was clear. But the back camera is still shaking

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem nobody can diagnose for you remotely. Take it to an Apple Store or a reputable Apple repair store.

Comment: UPDATE: The front camera is in perfect condition, and it was covered in a damaged cover/screen protector, and it let less light pass in. I removed it, and picture was clear. But the back camera is still having problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from replacing the camera, the solution to *temporarily* fix the shaking issue was to just place a magnet, yes a literal "magnet" near the camera. Somehow the magnet holds the camera and prevents it from shaking. I found this solution in YouTube videos. The magnet can be placed either around the camera on back-side, or right to the ear-piece on the front side, both would stop it.

Thanks